# Symfony - App uses wrong database name, CLI uses the correct one

Tags: mysql, symfony

hoping to get help with possibly a silly problem. I can't get Symfony to connect to the correct database.

My config line in .env is as follows

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/main?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.27"
```

Creating a database using CLI works just fine and the database named "main" is created

```
bin/console doctrine:database:create
Created database `main` for connection named default
```

Running migration works OK and a table is created in the database

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate

 WARNING! You are about to execute a migration in database "main" that could result in schema changes and data loss. Are you sure you wish to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

[notice] Migrating up to DoctrineMigrations\Version20230117183120
[notice] finished in 28.6ms, used 22M memory, 2 migrations executed, 3 sql queries
```

Yet, when I try to access the site from the browser I get the following error

```
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'root'
```

Clearing the cache doesn't seem to help, I don't see any reference in the code to a database named root. Any clues on how to make Symfony to connect to the "main" database?

Cheers
P.

Comment: Do you have multiple .env file ?

Comment: have you checked your doctrine.yaml service config file? is it as expected? maybe you mixed up the credentials.

Comment: hi, @Needpoule yes, there is only one .env file for sure

Comment: hi @user2403735 doctrine.yaml is not modified in any way and looks good to me. dbal urlis set to  '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%' and this is correctly set in .env to use main database

Comment: Well that'd be annoying...I know you said you cleared cache, but perhaps blow away the 'var' directory entirely and re-build? What happens when you run a SQL from console via `doctrine:query:sql`?? Does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Alex.Barylski, have tried clearing all in cache manually, still the same. Running the command returns `[OK] The query yielded an empty result set.` which is fine as the table is empty but confirms the connection from CLI works. I'm going to set up another project for now and leave this for later and debug when I have more time for it

Comment: Strange issue. Please share here when you figure it out, I'm curious to know.

Comment: I also have this issue. Did you manage to find it the cause?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "feature" of symfony CLI, which will generate `DATABASE_URL` based of your `docker-compose.yaml` file for your DB.
To disable this feature and to roll back on using your configured `DATABASE_URL` from your `.env` file, you need to update your docker-compose.yaml file and add these two lines in your DB service definition

```yaml
        labels:
            com.symfony.server.service-ignore: true
```

In my particular case, whole docker-compose.yaml looks like this

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
    database:
        image: 'mariadb'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        labels:
            com.symfony.server.service-ignore: true
```

More info about this feature in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#docker-integration)